# NLP translation giving me sentence translations instead of word translation

Tags: nlp, translation

I trained a Transformers using a Portuguese-English dataset from http://www.manythings.org/anki/. This is a parallelized sentence dataset.

After training, I tried translating the word "doente" which should've translated to "sick" but it instead I got "I feel sick".

Any ideas of how do I get just the word sick ?

Am I training my model with the wrong dataset ? sentence based instead of word based ?

tks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Machine translation generally works on sentences, as the context in which a word is used changes its meaning. There is no point in word-for-word translation.

So what will have happened is that your word *doente* usually occurs in sentences whose English translation is *I feel sick*; that is the minimal context. As these are all just characters to the machine, there is no 'understanding' that only the `sick` part corresponds to *doente* from the point of view of a human being.

If you want to translate words, use a bilingual dictionary; I doubt that there are word-based models for this, as decades of research in machine translation have shown that you need larger chunks of language for translating than just words.

Comment: Hi Oliver, tks for your reply. So just a quick question, how does google do it ? Do you have any idea of their approach ? NLP is not my research area and I was just trying to do something similar to Google translate just for fun.

Comment: I don't know how exactly google does it, but a common approach is to feed a machine learning system with parallel texts, where one sentence is the translation of the other; that way a mapping is established, but it is not word-by-word. It does, however, work with sentence fragments, not only complete sentences.